# Confusion about proof involving picking out element of ultrapower

Tags: logic, set-theory, proof-explanation, model-theory

Let $\kappa$ be measurable and $U$ the ultrafilter. Consider the ultrapower $\pi: V^{\kappa}/U \cong M$, where $\pi$ is the transitive collapse. We know that $\kappa \in M$, so there is some $f:\kappa \to V$ such that $[f]_U=\kappa$.

But I read in a proof that we can pick $f$ to have codomain $\kappa$ instead of $V$. But this seems wrong to me, since if $\{\alpha < \kappa : f(\alpha)<\kappa\} \in U$, then by Łoś we would have $M\models [f]_U<\kappa$, right? This means such an $f$ can't have codomain $\kappa$.

What am I missing?

Comment: Wrong. If $U$ is a $normal$ free ultrafilter then $\pi ([id_k]_U)=k,$ and if $f:k\to k$ such that $\{a\in k: f(a)>a\in U$ then $\pi ([f]_U)$ is an ordinal greater than $ k.$  Use the definitions: For $f:k \to V$ and $g:k\to V$ we define $ [f]_U\in^*[g]_U$ iff $\{a\in k:f(a)\in k\}\in U.$ And $\pi ([f]_U)=\{\pi ([g]_U:  [g]_U\in^*[f]_U\}.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, Łoś would tell you that for $f$ with codomain $\kappa$ you get $[f]_U<[c_\kappa]_U$, where $c_\kappa$ is the constant function with value $\kappa$. Or in other words, $[f]_U<j(\kappa)$, which is perfectly reasonable. In fact, the argument can be reversed, and any element of the ultrapower below $j(\kappa)$ can be represented by a function with codomain $\kappa$.